# How to rename a column in a spark scala dataframe after checking if it's present or not?

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to rename a column, "DOB" in my spark dataframe to "DateOfBirth" after checking if the column is available in the dataframe or not.

I am doing the below for renaming the column, but how do I insert the condition here

```scala
df.withColumnRenamed("DOB","DateOfBirth")
```

Could anyone please help on this.

Comment: There is no need for specifying any condition, as Spark does nothing if no column matches the provided column name.

Answer (score 1):

You can just check if the column exists with the `column()` function and only rename the column in that case:

```scala
val renamed_df = 
    if (df.columns.contains("DOB"))
        df.withColumnRenamed("DOB","DateOfBirth")
    else df
```